# PostgreSQL subquery not working

Tags: postgresql, subquery

What's wrong with this query?

```
select extract(week from created_at) as week, 
       count(*) as received, 
       (select count(*) from bugs where extract(week from updated_at) = a.week) as done
from bugs as a
group by week
```

The error message is:

> column a.week does not exist

UPDATE:

following the suggestion of the first comment, I tried this:

```
select a.extract(week from created_at) as week, 
   count(*) as received, (select count(*) 
from bugs 
where extract(week from updated_at) = a.week) as done from bugs as a group by week
```

But it doesn't seem to work:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "from"
LINE 1: select a.extract(week from a.created_at) as week, count(*) a...
```

Comment: You cannot reference an alias like that you need to use `a.extract(week from created_at)` instead

Comment: This makes sense but it doesn't seem to work. I could have misunderstood...

Comment: You cannot use `a.week` in the nested select.

Comment: Ok, I removed it, and the a.created_at as well but I still get the same error message. In the error message, the cursor is place in front of the first from (week from created_at). Without the a in front of extract, it works.

Comment: `a` is an table alias, you cannot call a function on it (`a.extract`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell you don't need the sub-select at all:

```
select extract(week from created_at) as week, 
       count(*) as received, 
       sum( case when extract(week from updated_at) = extract(week from created_at) then 1 end) as done
from bugs 
group by week
```

This counts all bugs per week and counts those that are updated in the same week as "done".

Note that your query will only report correct values if you never have more than one year in your table.

*If* you have more than one year of data in the table you need to include the year in the comparison as well:

```
select to_char(created_at, 'iyyy-iw') as week, 
       count(*) as received, 
       sum( case when to_char(created_at, 'iyyy-iw') = to_char(updated_at, 'iyyy-iw') then 1 end) as done
from bugs 
group by week
```

Note that I used `IYYY` an `IW` to cater for the ISO definition of the year and the week around the year end/start.

---

Maybe a little explanation on why your original query did not work would be helpful:

The "outer" query uses two aliases

- a table alias for `bugs` named `a`
- a column alias for the expression `extract(week from created_at)` named `week`

The *only* place where the *column* alias `week` can be used is in the `group by` clause.

To the sub-select `(select count(*) from bugs where extract(week from updated_at) = a.week))` the alias `a` is visible, but not the alias `week` (that's how the SQL standard is defined).

To get your subselect working (in terms of column visibility) you would need to reference the full expression of the "outer" column:

```
(select count(*) from bugs b where extract(week from b.updated_at) = extract(week from a.created_at))
```

Note that I introduced another table alias `b` in order to make it clear which column stems from which alias.

But even then you'd have a problem with the grouping as you can't reference an ungrouped column like that.

Answer (score 1):

that could work as well

```
with origin as (
  select extract(week from created_at) as week, count(*) as received
  from bugs
  group by week
)
select week, received, 
  (select count(*) from bugs where week = extract(week from updated_at) )
from origin
```

it should have a good performance

Comment: it's not the "with origin" its just "with 'name'". i used origin as name for the following query. replace origin with any other name you like